# How can I keep executing work while a button is pressed?

Tags: java, onclick, jbutton, buttonclick

I want to keep executing work while a button is pressed, using Java. When the button is released, the work should stop. Something like this:

```
Button_is_pressed()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        count=i;
        print "count"
    }
}
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Is this what you want ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719166/making-a-jbutton-stay-depressed-manually

Comment: I can't say this is a good idea, mostly because of the way the Event Queue works.  If you block when the button press occurs, you will never receive a mouse up event...

Comment: No What i want is Whnever user keep pressing the button then some process should start..and when user leave that pressed button then that should be stop

Comment: (I would) Use a `JToggleButton` (for this).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way:

- Add a ChangeListener to the JButton's ButtonModel
- In this listener check the model's `isPressed()` method and turn on or off a Swing Timer depending on its state.
- If you want a background process, then you can execute or cancel a SwingWorker in the same way.

An example of the former:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ButtonPressedEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int timerDelay = 100;
      final Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay , new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button Pressed!");
         }
      });

      JButton button = new JButton("Press Me!");
      final ButtonModel bModel = button.getModel();
      bModel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent cEvt) {
            if (bModel.isPressed() && !timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.start();
            } else if (!bModel.isPressed() && timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.stop();
            }
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(button);


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep executing work while a button is pressed

Execute that process in another thread and then your form is not block and you can press the button to cancel or stop the execution.

see :

- [How to stop threads of a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562465/how-to-stop-threads-of-a-java-program)
- [Stop/cancel SwingWorker thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083768/stop-cancel-swingworker-thread)
- [Control thread through button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179356/control-thread-through-button)

Answer (score 1):

You  may need to use `mousePressed` event to start the action

And use   `mouseReleased` event to stop the action   (This is neccesary)

For more information refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)

Comment: No, I urge you not to use a MouseListener for this. For one, the MouseListener will still work even if you try to prevent it from working by disabling the JButton. Best to avoid use of MouseListeners with JButtons in general.

Comment: @Hov I'd have +1'd for just the last sentence.  The rest of the comment was excellent advice as well.

Answer (score 0):

### For Android Apps

I know this question is old, but you can use:

```
while (yourButton.isPressed()) {

    // Do Stuff
}
```