# How can I run a function while a button pressed until release button in java application?

Tags: java, events, jbutton

I'm using java application. I have a button. When button clicked, fires `pressed` event. I want in `pressed` event run a function until `boolean myBool` be `true`. I use `myBool = false` in `released` event. But when I do it, it do `pressed` function event always and system crashed. **How can I do**?

Comment: I imagine you'd need some kind of background thread

Comment: I can't use thread. I have some restriction.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225052/how-can-i-keep-executing-work-while-a-button-is-pressed

Comment: can you share your code?
 may be, you are doing some minor mistake.

Comment: Well, frankly, you're screwed. Swing is a single threaded framework, you can't execute another method while the button is pressed, as this would prevent the button from ever been released

Comment: If you can't use another `Thread`, then there is no other solution which won't, at some point, use another thread...

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [d_ominic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3113920/d-ominic) and [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ButtonPressedEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int timerDelay = 100;
      final Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay , new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button Pressed!");
         }
      });

      JButton button = new JButton("Press Me!");
      final ButtonModel bModel = button.getModel();
      bModel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent cEvt) {
            if (bModel.isPressed() && !timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.start();
            } else if (!bModel.isPressed() && timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.stop();
            }
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(button);


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }
}
```