# How do I use a key listener (or some other method) to trigger a loop or method when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: java

Consider:

`public class CreateFileDir implements KeyListener{ 
    int i = 0;
    public boolean pressed = false;`

This is where I give and set the boolean "pressed" to false, and what I want it to do is when I press down the "x" key, it will switch it to true, and once released, false.

On a side note, I want this program to work outside of the IDE console. I got it to work without a key listener, but it has to work while running in background. I cannont use a toggle button unless I can bind it to a given key (x for example). I also have no popup just as JFrame I would like this to just run in background.

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
            pressed = false;
        }   
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
```

This is what my IDE (Eclipse) says I need to use key listener. My thought is that when I press and hold X down, pressed will become true, but as soon as I release X, press will go back to false

```
public void robo() throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        while(pressed) {
```

This is where I want the while loop to run when pressed is true. I tried to put it in main, but it says pressed would need to be static, which messes with the KeyListener methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CreateFileDir s2i = new CreateFileDir();
            while(1==1) {   
                    s2i.robo();
```

This is my main method where it constantly runs with the 1==1 `while` loop. I then want the `while(pressed)` when I press the X key.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I keep executing work while a button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225052/how-can-i-keep-executing-work-while-a-button-is-pressed)

Comment: Can I use the JToggleButton with a keybind? for my program I cannot left click on it, I need to to run when I press a given Key such as "x", also I am not using a JFrame or any pop up when It runs